# Is before update trigger will fire if same values are updating into a row of column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using before update trigger for each row on table, say emp_table to update one column modifid_date before loading into table. If I am going to update the table with same/existing values of a row, then is this trigger going to fire or not?

condition in trigger:
:new.modifid_dt  := sysdate;

Table Values before update: john (name),4867 (id),20-04-2016 (modifid_dt)
Table values now going to update: john (name),4867 (id)

Comment: have you tried testing the trigger to find if it is getting fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger will be fired, no matter the values you are using; for example:

```
SQL> create table testTrigger ( a number)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_update_trigger
  2    before update on testTrigger
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Trigger fired!');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into testTrigger values (10);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL>  update testTrigger set a = 10;
Trigger fired!

1 row updated.

SQL>  update testTrigger set a = 11;
Trigger fired!

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: It's possible to make a [conditional trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHBJHFE): _"A conditional trigger has a WHEN clause that specifies a SQL condition that the database evaluates for each row that the triggering statement affects."_ The trigger will still fire every time but the trigger's body might not be executes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want avoid "false" firing you should write trigger like this:

```
create or replace trigger trigger1 
before update on tst 
for each row 
begin
  IF :new.t_key != :old.t_key AND ... THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Trigger fired!');
  END IF;
end;
```

But beware of `NULL` values, of course.

Comment: Please use a [conditional trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHBJHFE) instead: _"A conditional trigger has a WHEN clause that specifies a SQL condition that the database evaluates for each row that the triggering statement affects."_

Answer (score 0):

New or existing values - no matter, anyway you'll perform an update so trigger will fire.

Comment: A [conditional trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHBJHFE) : _"A conditional trigger has a WHEN clause that specifies a SQL condition that the database evaluates for each row that the triggering statement affects."_ The trigger will fire, but the trigger's body might not be executed.

Comment: Yep, it is. Question was "will it fire?" so yes, it will fire and we don't know what topicstarter wants to do when it happens. Maybe he wants to perform actions only when same values updated? Vrebalism, huh.